Trying to upgrade lubuntu to 22.04 gets error
I get a dialog that 24.04 is available.
Then this message:
 Error when trying to upgrade to 24.04
 Could not determine the upgrade

 An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 The package 'postgresql-12' is marked for removal but it is in the removal deny list.

To prevent data loss, postgresql packages are not removed automatically during the upgrade. If you are certain you no longer need postgresql-12, you can manually remove it and try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

**** Removed postgesql files so can do upgrade to ubuntu 24.04
james@shire $ sudo rm -R /usr/lib/postgresql
james@shire $ sudo rm -R /etc/postgresql
james@shire $ sudo rm -R /usr/share/postgresql

I have broken packages should I remove them all?
Broken coreutils:amd64 Breaks on usrmerge:amd64 < 25ubuntu2 @ii mK > (< 39)
Broken python3:amd64 Conflicts on python3-distutils:amd64 < 3.10.8-1~22.04 @ii mK Ib >
Broken php-common:amd64 Breaks on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mK >
Broken nodejs:amd64 Breaks on libnode72:amd64 < 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.6 @ii mK > (< 13)
Broken liblxqt1:amd64 Breaks on liblxqt0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 0.99)
Broken libfm-qt14:amd64 Breaks on libfm-qt9:amd64 < 0.17.1-0ubuntu2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken pipewire-audio:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU >
Broken libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 Conflicts on libtss2-mu0:amd64 < 3.2.0-1ubuntu1.1 @ii gK >
Broken wireplumber:amd64 Conflicts on pipewire-media-session:amd64 < 0.4.1-2ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys1:amd64 Breaks on liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 0.99.0)
Broken libqtermwidget5-1:amd64 Breaks on libqtermwidget5-0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
Broken php8.1-mbstring:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-cli:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-opcache:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libpcre3:amd64 Breaks on libpcre3:i386 < 2:8.39-13ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii gK Ib > (!= 2:8.39-15build1)
Broken libboost1.83-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.74-dev:amd64 < 1.74.0-14ubuntu3 -> 1.74.0+ds1-23.1ubuntu3 @ii umU >
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys-ui1:amd64 Breaks on liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
Broken libasn1-8t64-heimdal:amd64 Depends on libroken19t64-heimdal:amd64 < none | 7.8.git20221117.28daf24+dfsg-5ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
Broken libwind0t64-heimdal:amd64 Depends on libroken19t64-heimdal:amd64 < none | 7.8.git20221117.28daf24+dfsg-5ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
Broken php8.1-readline:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-gd:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken pipewire-alsa:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU >
Broken libkf5screen-data:amd64 Breaks on libkf5screen7:amd64 < 4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 4:5.27.0~)
Broken libapache2-mod-php8.1:amd64 Depends on php8.1-cli:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libgegl-0.4-0t64:amd64 Depends on libumfpack6:amd64 < none | 1:7.6.1+dfsg-1build1 @un umH > (>= 1:7.0.1)
Broken libwayland-egl++1:amd64 Conflicts on libwayland-egl++0:amd64 < 0.2.8-2 @ii mK >
Broken libiw30t64:amd64 Conflicts on libiw30:amd64 < 30~pre9-13.1ubuntu4 @ii mK > (< 30~pre9-16.1ubuntu2)
Broken nautilus:amd64 Breaks on nautilus-extension-brasero:amd64 < 3.12.3-1 @ii mK > (< 3.12.3-2)
Broken libwayland-cursor++1:amd64 Conflicts on libwayland-cursor++0:amd64 < 0.2.8-2 @ii mK >
Broken libwayland-client++1:amd64 Conflicts on libwayland-client++0:amd64 < 0.2.8-2 @ii mK >
Broken libkrb5-26t64-heimdal:amd64 Depends on libasn1-8t64-heimdal:amd64 < none | 7.8.git20221117.28daf24+dfsg-5ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 1.6~git20131117)
Broken libkpmcore12:amd64 Breaks on libkpmcore11:amd64 < 21.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii mK >
Broken libboost-date-time1.83-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-date-time1.74-dev:amd64 < 1.74.0-14ubuntu3 -> 1.74.0+ds1-23.1ubuntu3 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libhx509-5t64-heimdal:amd64 Depends on libasn1-8t64-heimdal:amd64 < none | 7.8.git20221117.28daf24+dfsg-5ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
Broken libboost-regex1.83-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-regex1.74-dev:amd64 < 1.74.0-14ubuntu3 -> 1.74.0+ds1-23.1ubuntu3 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libgimp2.0t64:amd64 Depends on libgegl-0.4-0t64:amd64 < none | 1:0.4.48-2.4build2 @un umH > (>= 1:0.4.38)
Broken libcurl4t64:i386 Depends on libldap2:i386 < none | 2.6.7+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu8 @un umH > (>= 2.6.2)
Broken libboost-serialization1.83-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-serialization1.74-dev:amd64 < 1.74.0-14ubuntu3 -> 1.74.0+ds1-23.1ubuntu3 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gimp:amd64 Depends on libgimp2.0t64:amd64 < none | 2.10.36-3ubuntu0.24.04.1 @un umH > (>= 2.10.36)
Broken libboost-serialization1.74-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.74-dev:amd64 < 1.74.0-14ubuntu3 | 1.74.0+ds1-23.1ubuntu3 @ii umR > (= 1.74.0+ds1-23.1ubuntu3)
Broken fbreader:amd64 Breaks on libzlui-gtk:amd64 < 0.12.10dfsg2-6 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99)
Broken libgs-common:amd64 Breaks on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mK > (< 10)
Broken php8.1-xml:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-fpm:amd64 Depends on php8.1-cli:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libdleyna-core-1.0-6:amd64 Breaks on libdleyna-core-1.0-5:amd64 < 0.6.0-5build1 @ii gK >
Broken libheimntlm0t64-heimdal:amd64 Depends on libhcrypto5t64-heimdal:amd64 < none | 7.8.git20221117.28daf24+dfsg-5ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
Broken lubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on pipewire-audio:amd64 < none | 1.0.5-1ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken libguvcview-2.1-2t64:amd64 Breaks on libguvcview-2.0-2:amd64 < 2.0.7-2-1 @ii mK >
Broken php8.1:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 Depends on gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 -> 44.0-5build2 @ii umU > (< 43~)
Broken libvkd3d1:amd64 Breaks on libvkd3d1:i386 < 1.1-5 @ii mK Ib > (!= 1.2-15build1)
Broken libgssapi3t64-heimdal:amd64 Depends on libasn1-8t64-heimdal:amd64 < none | 7.8.git20221117.28daf24+dfsg-5ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
Broken php8.1-zip:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-bz2:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libmutter-10-0:amd64 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken php8.1-cgi:amd64 Depends on php8.1-cli:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libgnome-desktop-4-1:amd64 Depends on gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 -> 44.0-5build2 @ii umU > (< 43~)
Broken libstb0t64:amd64 Breaks on libstb0:i386 < 0.0~git20210910.af1a5bc+ds-1 @ii mK > (< 0.0~git20230129.5736b15+ds-1.2)
Broken php8.1-mysql:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-curl:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libfaudio0:amd64 Breaks on libfaudio0:i386 < 22.02-1 @ii mK Ib > (!= 24.02+dfsg-1build2)
Broken libpulsedsp:amd64 Depends on libpulse0:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU > (= 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2)
Broken libncurses5-dev:amd64 Depends on libtinfo6:amd64 < 6.3-2ubuntu0.1 -> 6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 6.3-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu8 @ii mR > (= 42.9-0ubuntu8)
Broken libfm-gtk4:amd64 Depends on libfm4:amd64 < 1.3.2-1 @ii pmR > (= 1.3.2-1)
Broken libfwupdplugin5:amd64 Depends on libfwupd2:amd64 < 1.7.9-1~22.04.3 -> 1.9.24-1~24.04.1 @ii umU > (= 1.7.9-1~22.04.3)
Broken php8.1-pgsql:amd64 Depends on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libgnustep-base1.28:amd64 Depends on gnustep-base-common:amd64 < 1.28.0-4build1 -> 1.29.0-7ubuntu4 @ii umU > (= 1.28.0-4build1)
Broken libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64 Depends on libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 < 7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1 @ii pgR > (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
Broken libgs9:amd64 Depends on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mR > (= 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9)
Broken pcp:amd64 Depends on libpcp-archive1t64:amd64 < none | 6.2.0-1.1build4 @un umH > (= 6.2.0-1.1build4)
Broken libgnutlsxx28:amd64 Depends on libgnutls30:amd64 < 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.5 @ii pmR > (= 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.5)
Broken libgnome-bg-4-1:amd64 Depends on libgnome-desktop-4-1:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 3.17.92)
Broken libgphoto2-6t64:i386 Depends on libcurl4t64:i386 < none | 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4 @un umH > (>= 7.16.2)
Broken libboost-date-time1.83-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-serialization1.83-dev:amd64 < none | 1.83.0-2.1ubuntu3 @un uH > (= 1.83.0-2.1ubuntu3)
Broken libwine:i386 Depends on libgphoto2-6t64:i386 < none | 2.5.31-2.1build2 @un umH > (>= 2.5.10)
Broken wine32:i386 Depends on libwine:i386 < 6.0.3~repack-1 | 9.0~repack-4build3 @ii umR NPb > (= 9.0~repack-4build3)
Broken libldap-2.4-2:amd64 Depends on libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 < 7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1 @ii pmR > (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
Broken postgresql-12:amd64 Depends on libldap-2.4-2:amd64 < 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.9 @ii mR > (>= 2.4.7)
Broken libboost-date-time-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-date-time1.83-dev:amd64 < none | 1.83.0-2.1ubuntu3 @un uH >
Broken pulseaudio-module-gsettings:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umR > (= 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10)
Broken pipewire-audio:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU >
Broken pipewire-audio:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:i386 < none | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @un uH >
Broken pulseaudio-module-gsettings:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umR > (= 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10)
Broken pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umR > (= 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10)
Broken pulseeffects:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umR >
Broken paprefs:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio-module-gsettings:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umR >
Broken pulseaudio-module-jack:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umR > (= 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10)
Broken audio-recorder:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umR >

I'm just trying to do the upgrade to 24.04 from 22.04.

Postgresql 16 is the offering in Ubuntu 24.04, and Postgresql 14 was the Ubuntu 22.04 version. Postgresql 12 may be a leftover from an Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 upgrade.
Historically, Database upgrades typically take a conservative approach, get the new one running and validated before deleting the old one. To allow running simultaneously, a different listening port is assigned: typically the default 5432 port on the running postgresql is kept and the new postgresql is assigned the next one, 5433.
When you have dumped the old db, loaded the new db, run your tests, you then may delete the old db, and likely change the listening port back to the default, 5432.
The upgrade process doesn't look like it is designed to handle arbitrarily old databases. Also, the conservative approach might be dropped at any time, and all the dump old, load new automated, forgoing any validation testing.
Best to have a current dump available before the upgrade, so whatever happens, you have backup that can be reloaded into whatever db release is desired.  So , dump your pg12 db, install and test pg14 if you like to validate/test, then your upgrade to pg 16 should work.  In any case, have your data dump backed up.
